# Does efficient GLCM gliding window exist in Python library?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, glcm

I am using scikit-image's greycomatrix (GLCM) to extract features from an image. This method is quite fast, but when creating a feature map of an image with GLCM one needs to glide a window over the image and call greycomatrix once for each window. For a 256x256 image that is 65536 calls. This becomes very slow with simple Python loops. I have been searching high and low, but I cannot find an existing implementation of this window gliding method, so I have made it myself so far. It seems strange that this doesn't already exist within scikit-image since this is the primary way to use the GLCM.

In the scikit-image GLCM tutorial (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_glcm.html) they only analyse a few individual windows and say nothing about gliding windows. That is not very helpful.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix
from skimage.data import coins

def glide(image, w, d, theta, levels=16):

    image = np.pad(image, int(w/2), mode='reflect')  # Add padding.
    M, N = image.shape
    feature_map = np.zeros((M, N))  # Placeholder for some feature.

    for m in xrange(0, M):
        for n in xrange(0, N):
            window = image[m:m+w, n:n+w]
            glcm = greycomatrix(window, d, theta, levels)
            # Do something with glcm: Find variance, entropy, etc.
            feature_map[m,n] = 1.  # Compute something here.

feature_map = glide(coins(), w=21, d=[5], theta=[0], levels=256)
```

This is my custom gliding window method. Does a more efficient version of this already exist within scikit-image or similar?

Comment: Perhaps the following are useful: ``skimage.util.view_as_windows``, ``skimage.util.view_as_blocks``, ``skimage.util.apply_parallel`` (see http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/api.html)

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Yes, this is it! `skimage.util.apply_parallel` does exactly what I need! This should be mentioned in the GLCM tutorial. However, I am unable to import it. `skimage.util.apply_parallel` just doesn't exist in my `skimage.util`... And I do have the latest version of `skimage` (0.11.3). What is going on here? `skimage.util.view_as_windows` works fine, but with this I still have to loop through all the windows, so it's a minor improvement.

Comment: That functionality will only be available in the next release.  But I'm glad that it works for you!  You can also just grab the source code from the Git repository.